# Setting session_id unreliable when using flash to send data

Tags: php, flash, uploadify, sessionid

I'm using PHP version 5.3.2 on both my local development server and remote web server.

I'm trying to use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload several files to the server.  In the receiving script, I would like to use data stored in the session, however because uploadify sends files to the script using flash it doesn't send the session cookie.
The workaround for this problem is to get uploadify to GET or POST the session id to the script, however I'm finding this very unreliable.
In my script I have the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', TRUE);
session_name('SESSNAME');
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The script url is something like script.php?SESSNAME=*sessionid* and I have tried using transparent session ids as above and also manually setting the id using session_id($_GET['SESSNAME']).

This *always* works when accessing the script directly with the browser and sending the current session id along, even if I manually delete the session cookie.  It also always works with uploadify on my local server.  However when using uploadify on the remote server, it works about 20% of the time, completely randomly.  There is no pattern.  It seemed to work with greater frequency when I added

```
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
```

to the script, however this may have been just coincidence.

Local server info: http://www.dur.ac.uk/n.r.brook/info_local.php
Remote server info: http://www.dur.ac.uk/n.r.brook/info.php

---

### Some speculation...

Doing some digging around and looking at the headers the script is receiving, I think I may have determined the issue.
You need to send the session id when using uploadify because flash does not send cookies when using the FileReference.upload() (I think!) method.  However, as well as the session id, in load balanced environments (such as the remote server) there is also the BALANCEID cookie which determines which server the user is currently working with.  Flash doesn't send this cookie so the load balancer sometimes sends the request to a different server, and on this server the session does not exist.

I have tested this behaviour by setting a session variable after I have printed the session.  Doing this and repeatedly sending files exhibits the issue - at first I get an empty array, but a few repeats in the variable starts appearing.

So, if the above is all true, then my question is what can I do to get flash to send this data with the upload so the load balancer knows which server to use?  Or is this a lost cause?

---

### The answer?

After further research, I found the following post - http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/977
This suggests there is no way cookies can be sent with FileReference.upload() and therefore uploadify cannot be used with load balanced servers if you want to use session data.  However, I think I will now attempt a solution which saves data linked to the session id to a file.  The uploadify receiving script can open this file and pull out the required data.
This is my first experience working with anything Flash based, it has not improved my opinion of the technology!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem is:

In the 'upload' page:

```
 file_put_contents($some_folder.'/'.session_id(), serialize($just_the_vars_you_will_be_using));
```

In your javascript that loads uploadify:

```
 var start = document.cookie.indexOf("PHPSESSID=");
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", start); // First ; after start
 if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length; // failed indexOf = -1
 var cookie = document.cookie.substring(start+10, end);
 $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : 'uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
            'auto'      : true,
            'multi'     : true,
            'scriptData': { SESSID : cookie }
 });
```

In the script that receives the files:

```
 $vars = unserialize(file_get_contents($some_folder.'/'.$_POST['SESSID']));
```

If you want to write back to the 'session' in this script, at the end:

```
 file_put_contents($some_folder.'/'.$_POST['SESSID'], serialize($vars));
```

As far as I know, there shouldn't be any security issues associated with this, as you will only be using a handful of variables stored in the file (I only store an incrementing value and a temporary file path).  Make sure there is an index.html in $some_folder to prevent file listing.

Comment: Nick, how do you think this would work with a large number of concurrent script runs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can use cookies when sending from flash. 
Cookies is needed for php to find the session storage id. The value that is stored in the cookie is actual the session id and the cookie name is in most cases the session name. 
To get the session in php can´t be done by typing $_SESSION['name'] but you can make your own session library that you include. This will let php get all of the nassery values and you can continue.

Here is a session library that I put together in php:

```
function SESSION_OPEN($PATH,$NAME){
    global $SESSION_PATH, $SESSION_NAME;
    $SESSION_PATH=$PATH;
    $SESSION_NAME=$NAME;

    return(true);
}

function SESSION_CLOSE(){
    return(true);
}

function SESSION_GET($ID){
    global $SESSION_PATH, $SESSION_NAME;
    $STR_PATH="$SESSION_PATH/USES_".session_id()."_$ID";

    if($RESOURCE = @fopen($STR_PATH,"r")){
        $CONTENT = @fread($RESOURCE ,filesize($STR_PATH));  
        return($CONTENT);   
    }else{
        return(false);  
    }
}

function SESSION_PUT($ID,$VALUE){
    global $SESSION_PATH, $SESSION_NAME;
    $STR_PATH="$SESSION_PATH/USES_".session_id()."_$ID";

    if($RESOURCE = @fopen($STR_PATH,"w")){
        fwrite($RESOURCE , $VALUE );    
        return(true);   
    }else{
        return(false);  
    }
}

function SESSION_DEST($ID){
    global $SESSION_PATH, $SESSION_NAME;
    $STR_PATH="$SESSION_PATH/USES_".session_id()."_$ID";

    return(@unlink($STR_PATH));
}

function SESSION_GC($MAX_EXECUTION){
    return(true);   
}

session_set_save_handler("SESSION_OPEN","SESSION_CLOSE","SESSION_GET","SESSION_PUT","SESSION_DEST","SESSION_GC");
```